# Remove Column from CSV file using SSIS

Tags: ssis, script-task

I have a CSV file that I am using as a source in SSIS. The file contains additional blank columns in the file

[image: CSV FILE SAMPLE]

There is an additional column in S, U, V; is there a way I can remove the column through SSIS Script Task before using it as a source file.

Comment: Help me understand what you're attempting to do. Take a CSV with blank columns and then rewrite it without the blank columns?

Comment: You are going to have a lot more issues than just blank columns.

Comment: @billinkc I want to load this file into a SQL server table. This just part of the while. What do you mean by Take a CSV with blank columns and then re-write it without blank column?

Comment: @KeithL that's the only issue I have. I am happy to hear a solution if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the problem, but you have a CSV with blank columns that you'd like to import into SQL Server but you do not want to import the blank columns into your table.

So, don't create the target columns in your table. That's it. There's no problem with having "extra" data in your data pipeline, just don't land it.

The Flat File Connection manager must<sup>*</sup> have a definition for all the columns. As it appears you do not headers for the blank columns and a column name is required, you will need to set up the flat file connection manager as my file has no header columns but then skip 1 row to avoid the header row. It might be a data starts on line setting - doing this from memory. By specifying no header row, that means you need to manually provide your column names. I favor naming them something obvious like IgnoreBlankColumn_S, IgnoreBlankColumn_U, IgnoreBlankColumn_V that way future maintainers will know this is an intentional design decision since the source data has no data.

<sup>*</sup>You *can* write a query against a text file which would allow you to only pull in specific columns but this is not going to be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but it's not working. If you see the Due Date column if the first value is null, SSIS package at the first step which is Source

Comment: For the Due Date column, there is no value in the first data row. What is supposed to happen?